# Select subgroups with replacement in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I saw many similar procedures : select rows from groups in a dataframe, etc. But this is not what I need.

**Is there any quick and easy way to select groups with replacement in a dataframe ?**

R Code Example:

```
> df = cbind(id = 1:10, groups = sample(1:3, 10, replace  = T))
> df
      id groups
 [1,]  1      3
 [2,]  2      3
 [3,]  3      2
 [4,]  4      2
 [5,]  5      1
 [6,]  6      3
 [7,]  7      1
 [8,]  8      2
 [9,]  9      1
[10,] 10      1
```

I need to select randomly 3 groups, with replacement among the 3 groups.
So, for example, if **my selection is groups 1, 1 and 2**, my final dataframe will be the following:

```
> rbind(df[ df[,'groups'] == 1, ], df[ df[,'groups'] == 1, ], df[ df[,'groups'] == 2, ])
      id groups
 [1,]  5      1
 [2,]  7      1
 [3,]  9      1
 [4,] 10      1
 [5,]  5      1
 [6,]  7      1
 [7,]  9      1
 [8,] 10      1
 [9,]  3      2
[10,]  4      2
[11,]  8      2
```

How should I proceed ?

NB : My dataframe is constituted with many variables. I need a complete dataframe at the end with the selected individuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate your group sample:

```
x <- sample(unique(df$groups), 3, replace = TRUE)
```

Then select the appropriate parts of df:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(i) df[df$groups == i,]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, we can select 3 random `groups` with replacement using `sample_n` and then do a `left_join` with the original `df` to get corresponding rows with those groups.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  distinct(groups) %>%
  sample_n(3, replace = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df)

#   groups id
#1       2  4
#2       2  6
#3       2  7
#4       2  8
#5       2  4
#6       2  6
#7       2  7
#8       2  8
#9       3  1
#10      3  2
#11      3  3
#12      3  5
#13      3  9
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(id = 1:10, groups = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elegant solution (sorry to add a comment to thank :-) )